# How to make HTML input tag only accept numbers?

Tags: html, meteor

How to make `HTML` input tag only accept numbers?

- I need to make sure that `input` field only takes numbers as input
  value.
- I want the user to be unable to type in any other characters other
  than numbers.
- User manually enters the number not a number scroll bar.

I am using the `Meteor Js`.And the code as shown below.

```
App.html

<head>
  <title App</title>
</head>

<body>
  {{> main}}

</body>

<template name="main">
     <h1>Welcome to TICTACTOE App</h1>
    <p><b>Layout Number :</b> <input type="text" id="no"></p>
</template>



App.js


if (Meteor.isClient)
 {


  Template.main.events
  ({
    'keydown input#no' : function ()
    {
      // template data, if any, is available in 'this'
      if (event.which == 13) 
        { // 13 is the enter key event
          console.log("You pressed  enter key");
        }
    }
  });
}

if (Meteor.isServer) 
{
  Meteor.startup(function () 
  {
    // code to run on server at startup
  });
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to allow only numeric (0-9) in HTML  inputbox using jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/995183/how-to-allow-only-numeric-0-9-in-html-inputbox-using-jquery)

Comment: And possible duplicate of  [HTML Text Input allow only Numeric input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/469357/html-text-input-allow-only-numeric-input)

Answer (score 2):

This should help you.

```
<input type="number" />
```

:)

Or Best way to use jQuery with keycodes:

```
jQuery("#yourInputId").keydown(function(event) {
            // Allow: backspace, delete, tab, escape, enter and .
            if ( jQuery.inArray(event.keyCode,[46,8,9,27,13,190]) !== -1 ||
                 // Allow: Ctrl+A
                (event.keyCode == 65 && event.ctrlKey === true) || 
                 // Allow: home, end, left, right
                (event.keyCode >= 35 && event.keyCode <= 39)) {
                     // let it happen, don't do anything
                     return;
            }
            else {
                // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
                if (event.shiftKey || (event.keyCode < 48 || event.keyCode > 57) && (event.keyCode < 96 || event.keyCode > 105 )) {
                    event.preventDefault(); 
                }   
            }
        });
```

See [DEMO.](http://jsfiddle.net/4HHeQ/)

Comment: actually i was talking about your previous post of <input type="number" />

Answer (score 1):

if you use HTML5 then

```
<input type="number" />
```

else

```
<script>
     function isNumberKey(evt){
            var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
            return !(charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57));
        }
</script>

<input type="text" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event);">
```

Answer (score 1):

With HTML5 it's easy:

```
<input type="number" />
```

If HTML5 is not supported use jQuery events: [Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9aJ8f/)

```
<label for="number">Number: </label>
<input type="text" name="number" id="number" />

<script>
    $('#number').keydown(function(){
        $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^\d]/,''));
        $(this).keyup(function(){
            $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^\d]/,''));
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function isNumberKey(evt){
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
        return false;
    return true;
}

<input type="someid" name="number" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

will work only with HTML 5. 
If you want it to work for older browser as well you have to take help of javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<input name="amount" type="text" value="Only number in here"/> 

<script>
    $('input[name=amount]').keyup(function(){
        $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^\d]/,''));
    });
</script>
```

You can also use the pattern attribute in html5:

```
<input type="text" name="name" pattern="[0-9]" title="Title" />
```

Answer (score 0):

On any input you need filter, you only need put the **onkeydown="return onlynumbers(event);"**
code.
This is a generic code that will work on old HTML and does not need jQuery. :)

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function onlynumbers(e) {
        if (e.shiftKey === true ) {
            if (e.which == 9) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
        if (e.which > 57) {
            return false;
        }
        if (e.which==32) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
</script>
<input type="text" onkeydown="return onlynumbers(event);">
```